# Syncing with deleted IMAP account

Tags: windows, email, outlook, imap, synchronization

Due to server data loss, I will have to recreate IMAP e-mail accounts for a client. He still have copies of old e-mails locally in Outlook.

My question is: when Outlook syncs again with the new, empty, IMAP account, will the old e-mails be deleted on his computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old emails will be deleted once the server comes back online with an empty account.
Copy the emails to PST file, then when your server is back online and both accounts are sync copy them back in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of the existing outlook profile by exporting it into pst file and suggest you to setup new profile with imap settings. 
Once outlook/email client is setup with new account, please import pst file into this new profile which should then sync with server.